# conditional probability related to drawing coins with 2 properties

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, discrete-distributions

I'm not quite familiar with conditional probability, and is having difficulty coming with a solution of the following problem:

There are 3 coins in a box, and each of them is associated with 1 of the 4 values: 1, 2, 5, 10 with a probability of 1/4. Each coin's value is independent from each other. Besides, each coin has a 50% chance of being in gold or silver. The color of the coin is independent of its value.

Question 1. If at least two coins are in gold, what is the probability that all 3 coins are in gold?

Question 2. If at least two of the coins are gold and of value 1, what is the probability that all 3 coins are gold?

My general idea for Q1 is let $X$ be the #gold coins, Q1 is asking for $P(X=3 | X \geq 2)$ which is $P((X=3) \cap (X \geq 2)) / P(X \geq 2) = P(X=3) / P(X \geq 2) = 1/4$. Not sure if it's correct?

For Q2, if let $X_G$ be the #gold coins, and $X_{G, 1}$ be the number of gold coins of value 1. We want to compute $P(X_G = 3 | X_{G, 1})$ but I don't have a good idea how to calculate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Q1, you made a good start. To reach to the final answer, note that $X \sim B(3, p)$, with $p = P[\text{a randomly selected coin is golden}] = 0.5$, whence $P[X = 3] = p^3 = 1/8$, and $P[X \geq 2] = P[X = 2] + P[X = 3] = \binom{3}{2}(1 - p)p^2 + p^3 = \frac{1}{2}$.  Therefore, the desired probability is $\frac{1/8}{1/2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Q2 is more tricky and a better notation system would help.  Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ be the color and value of the $i$-th coin respectively, $i = 1, 2, 3$. By condition, $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2), (X_3, Y_3)$ are independent, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent, $i = 1, 2, 3$.

The conditioning event $E$ is a disjoint union of events $E_1$ and $E_2$, where $E_1$ is the event *exactly two coins are gold and of value $1$*, and $E_2$ is the event *three coins are gold and of value $1$*. Therefore,
\begin{align}
P(E_1) =& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (G, 1), (X_3, Y_3) \neq (G, 1)] \\
        & + P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), (X_2, Y_2) \neq (G, 1)] \\
        & + P[(X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), (X_1, Y_1) \neq (G, 1)], \\
P(E_2) =& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1)].
\end{align}

By assumption,
\begin{align}
P(E_2) = P[(X_1, Y_1) = (G, 1)]^3 = P[X_1 = G]^3P[Y_1 = 1]^3 = 0.5^3 \times 0.25^3 = \frac{1}{512}.
\end{align}
To evaluate $P(E_1)$, by symmetry, it suffices to evaluate
\begin{align}
 & P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (G, 1), (X_3, Y_3) \neq (G, 1)] \\
=& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (G, 1)]^2P[(X_3, Y_3) \neq (G, 1)] \\
=& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (G, 1)]^2(1 - P[(X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1)]) \\
=& \frac{1}{8} \times \frac{1}{8} \times \frac{7}{8} = \frac{7}{512}. 
\end{align}
Hence $P(E_1) = 3 \times \frac{7}{512} = \frac{21}{512}$, and $P(E) = P(E_1) + P(E_2) = \frac{22}{512} = \frac{11}{256}$.

The event $A := [X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = G] \cap E$ is
\begin{align}
     & [(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1)] \\
\cup & [(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (G, 1), X_3 = G, Y_3 \neq 1] \\
\cup & [(X_1, Y_1) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), X_2 = G, Y_2 \neq 1] \\
\cup & [(X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), X_1 = G, Y_1 \neq 1],
\end{align}
in which
\begin{align}
& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1)] = \frac{1}{8^3} = \frac{1}{512}, \\
& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_2, Y_2) = (G, 1), X_3 = G, Y_3 \neq 1] \\
=& P[(X_1, Y_1) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), X_2 = G, Y_2 \neq 1] \\
=& P[(X_2, Y_2) = (X_3, Y_3) = (G, 1), X_1 = G, Y_1 \neq 1]\\
=& \frac{1}{8^2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{512}.
\end{align}
Hence $P[X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = G] \cap E] = \frac{1}{512} + 3 \times \frac{3}{512} = \frac{5}{256}$, and the probability of interest is
\begin{align}
 & P[X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = G | E] \\
=& \frac{P[[X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = G] \cap E]}{P(E)} \\
=& \frac{\frac{5}{256}}{\frac{11}{256}} = \frac{5}{11}. 
\end{align}

#### An Alternative Solution using Classical Probability Model (Q2)

The above solution essentially used axioms of probability measure. By the independence assumption, this problem can also be approached with the classical probability model view using basic counting techniques, for which the sample space is defined as
\begin{align}
\Omega = \{(c_1, v_1, c_2, v_2, c_3, v_3): c_i \in \{G, S\}, v_i
\in \{1, 2, 5, 10\}, i = 1, 2, 3\}.
\end{align}
Clearly, $|\Omega| = 2^3 \times 4^3 = 512$, $|E| = 1 + \binom{3}{2}\times (2 \times 4 - 1) = 22$ ($1$ corresponds to the outcome $(G, 1, G, 1, G, 1)$. The second term is the number of ways of getting exactly two gold coins of value $1$: there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of picking up two gold coins of value $1$, for the remaining one coin, it cannot be gold and of value $1$, which has $8 - 1$ choices), $|A| = 1 + \binom{3}{2} \times 3 = 10$ ($1$ corresponds to the outcome $(G, 1, G, 1, G, 1)$. The second term is the number of ways of getting exactly two gold coins of value $1$, one gold coin whose value is not $1$: there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of picking up two gold coins of value $1$, for the remaining one coin, it is gold but is not of value $1$, which has $3$ choices). Therefore, the answer is
\begin{align}
\frac{|A|/|\Omega|}{|E|/|\Omega|} = \frac{|A|}{|E|} = \frac{10}{22} = \frac{5}{11}. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. For Q1, I think you only included P(X=2)'s value in your denominator?

Comment: Right, I will update.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about your Q2 solution: the numerator in your conditional probability became equivalent to the probability that all three coins are gold and of value 1.  It excluded cases where 2 coins are gold and value 1, and 1 coin are gold  but of other values.

Comment: Probably you're right. I need to revise the numerator later.

Comment: @user21 Corrected earlier errors.  I also added an alternative solution which may be more succinct.